# Use the value of "Database log messages to keep" that user select

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How i can select the number that the user select on path: **admin/config/development/logging** and i want the number under **Database log messages to keep** I want to take this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is stored in the `variable` table and uses a default value of 1000. To retrieve the value you can use:

```
variable_get('dblog_row_limit', 1000);
```

Comment: i want to take the value when cron runs. And i want to get the value that the user had select.. Is that the line of code that i need?

Comment: Yes, this is the value selected by the user under `admin/config/development/logging`